# Jaspersoft Studio compiling legacy reports throws net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm trying to use the Compatibility features in Jaspersoft Studio 6.5.1(latest), but I get the following error when compiling reports:

```
 "package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist".
```

[image]

I use properties > Jaspersoft Studio > Compatibility to load previous versions of jasper reports.

[image]

I then select a previous version for the compiler

[image]

I also tried adding the legacy versions directly to the build path...

[image]

..But that didn't resolve the error. 
I'm running it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the jasperreports-x.x.x-project.zip from sourceforge and unzip each one, then set the JasperStudio managed version location at each folder you unzipped to you should hopefully find that solves your problem

Comment: thanks. I'll giving it a go. Any reason why the built in downloader/path url wouldn't work?

Comment: Kudos! That solved the compile error. Unfortunately running the report gives me "NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setTabs(", so still some work left for me, but you got me unstuck..